# usb_cam low FPS from webcam

Tags: ros, usb-cam, camera, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I found out I can use usb_cam to publish images from my webcam. I tested it with my laptop's webcam and it performs poorly, only 7 FPS.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric

ROS: Electric (installed via apt-get)

dmesg output regarding webcam:

> [ 7209.629430] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
> [ 7211.188071] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
> [ 7211.383400] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device CNF7231 (04f2:b073)
> [ 7211.395092] input: CNF7231 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input11

I downloaded http://www.ros.org/wiki/usb_cam and compiled it using rosmake.
Compilation log: http://pastebin.com/rJYMR0Bw

As you can see it complains about libswscale (although I have it installed) but it managed to compile it.

Starting usb_cam gives the following output:
http://pastebin.com/6JQ2CSpP

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12198/usb_cam-low-fps-from-webcam/) by [Rosia Nicolae](https://answers.ros.org/users/1487/rosia-nicolae/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-02-16**:
Have you tried other webcam software? Webcam support in linux is...spotty...at best. Do guvcview, or cheese, or similar, give you better behavior? It's not necessarily ROS' fault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can try another pixel format, my launch file for my usb webcam looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node">
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
  </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also try with: http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera
This one has a`~fps` parameter to set the framerate.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2